# Integer coefficients such that $T(n,k)=R(n,k)-R(n,k-1)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients, integer-sequences

Let $a(n)$ be [A000085](https://oeis.org/A000085), i.e., the number of self-inverse permutations on $n$ letters, also known as involutions; number of standard Young tableaux with $n$ cells. Here
$$a(n) = a(n-1) + (n-1)a(n-2), a(0)=a(1)=1$$
Let $b(n)$ be [A038205](https://oeis.org/A038205), i.e., the number of derangements of $n$ where minimal cycle size is at least 3. Here
$$b(n) = (n-1)b(n-1) + (n-1)(n-2)b(n-3), b(0)=1, b(1)=b(2)=0$$
Let $T(n,k)$ be an integer coefficients such that
$$T(n,k)=[n=0]\cdot[k=0] + [n>0](kT(n-1,k)+T(n-1,k-1)+T(n-1,k-2))$$
Here square brackets denote Iverson brackets.

Let $R(n,k)$ be an integer coefficients such that
$$R(n,k)=\frac{1}{k!}\sum\limits_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j} j^n a(j) b(k-j)$$

I conjecture that
$$T(n,k)=R(n,k)-R(n,k-1)$$

Here is the PARI prog to verify this conjecture:

```
a(n)=if(n<2, 1, a(n-1) + (n-1)*a(n-2))
b(n)=if(n<3, n==0, (n-1)*b(n-1) + (n-1)*(n-2)*b(n-3))
T(n, k)=if(n==0, k==0, k*T(n-1, k) + T(n-1, k-1) + T(n-1, k-2))
R(n, k)=sum(j=0, k, j^n*a(j)*b(k-j)/(j!*(k-j)!))
T1(n)=my(v); v=vector(2*n, i, T(n, i))
R1(n)=my(v, v1); v=vector(2*n+1, i, R(n, i-1)); v1=vector(2*n, i, v[i+1]-v[i])
test(n)=T1(n)==R1(n)
```

Is there a way to prove it?